# Accelerating VBA macro (now using For... and If...)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I use macro with following code:

```
   For i = 1 To IMAX - 1
      If Range("B" & IMAX - i).Value = 0 Then
         Rows(IMAX - i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
      Else
      End If
   Next i
```

```
IMAX is about 1500
ScreenUpdating is False
```

Do you have any recommendation how to accelerate it?

Comment: It seemed to me that you didn't have much to look for, except ScreenUpdating and xlCalculationManual

Comment: when deleting you should always go from the bottom up OR better yet, use @taller answer, which is the best option.  it's usually better to avoid loops as they're slow.

Comment: Search "[Excel] delete rows slow" you'll find hundreds of posts, suggesting a variety of way to speed this up

Answer (score 2):

- Apply autofilter on Col B (filter zero), then delete visible rows
- Assuming the data table starts from cell A1 and has a header row

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [AutoFilter object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm537072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range
    With ActiveSheet  ' modify as needed
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="0"
            Set c = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                c.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In my simple test this is better

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, is to have the macro cycle from the bottom row and work its way up to the top. Make sure to have xlCalculationManual and Application.Screenupdating false.

Personally, I like taller's reply the best

Answer (score 0):

Temporary stop the automatic calulation of sheets.

```
' Before For      
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'[Youre code here...]
 
' After Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub DotLastColumn(Optional Put_Remove As Boolean = True)
    Dim t_Put_Remove As Boolean
    
    t_Put_Remove = Put_Remove
    Select Case t_Put_Remove
    Case True, False
    Case Else: t_Put_Remove = True
    End Select
    
    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
            LCol = Columns(Split(Split(.UsedRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(1)).Column + 0
        If Err Then LCol = 1
        On Error Resume Next
            LRow = Split(Split(.UsedRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(2) + 0
        If Err Then LRow = 1
    End With
    
    Select Case t_Put_Remove
    Case True
        Range(Cells(1, LCol + 1), Cells(LRow, LCol + 1)).Value = "."
    Case False
        Range(Cells(1, LCol), Cells(LRow, LCol)).Delete
    End Select
End Sub
Public Sub SortbyDot()
    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
        LCol = Columns(Split(Split(.UsedRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(1)).Column + 0
        If Err Then LCol = 1
    End With
    Cells.Sort Key1:=Cells(1, LastCol), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
End Sub
Public Sub ConditionalRowDelete_Loop()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Call DotLastColumn
    
    Dim delRange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To IMAX
            If Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    
        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Value = vbNullString
    End With
    
    Call SortbyDot
    
    Call DotLastColumn(False)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an attractive option.I wanted to see it too.  But it is 14 times slower in plain text than the original version

Comment: Edit post.Tricky long way.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your range data to an array, do your calculations and/or string manipulation on that array, then place the array results back into your range.  It will be exponentially faster than touching each cell as you're currently doing.